# joomla entirely custom url

Tags: url, joomla1.7

I want to give entirely custom url to my article
something like: `/games/2010/junee2010/6/Dexter%20the%20Game.html`
Because I am move html based site to Joomla and I want to save same urls for Google.
What extension or custom solution I need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of good SEF extensions that can probably do it -

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/10134

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/10019

However, I am not a big fan of using SEF extensions, the built in SEF works pretty well. Unless you have hundreds of articles you are moving, I would use 301 redirects and let Joomla build the URLs the way it would normally. One less thing to go wrong.